# jQuery add padding-right with width of a child element

Tags: jquery, css

I need to add padding-right css with width from a child element. This is how I think it to do:

jQuery

```
$('.parent_element').css('padding-right', $(this).children('.child_element').width() + 'px');
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="parent_element"><i class="fa"></i> Example <span class="child_element">101</span></a>
```

But it doesn't add this css to the parent element.

Comment: What is `$(this)` referring to? Or what do you think it is referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function as [second argument](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```
$('.parent_element').css('padding-right', function () {
  return $(this).children('.child_element').width() + 'px';
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/xusima/1/edit?css,js,output)

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your code will be the value of `this` in the current scope, not the target of the `.css` method. To achieve what you want, you need to create a new scope. To do that, you can pass a function to `.css` that return the desired value :

```
$('.parent_element').css('padding-right', function(){
    return $(this).children('.child_element').width() + 'px'
});
```